# Share configs of a project between several projects in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, share

I have a project called SPI with 15 configs. Those configs have dependency on a build config of project A.
I have been asked to run those same 15 SPI configs for project B and C. A, B and C are not dependent on each other. One way to do it is replicate the SPi project for B and C. But maintenance will be a nightmare. DO you have any suggestions on how to address this situation? DO you think I should use meta-runner? It will reduce the maintenance but not remove it. Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Teamcity are you using?  Teamcity 8 has Build Configuration templates.  I'm not sure when they were first introduced but if you have access to them, I'd recommend using them.

You can create build configuration templates from existing ones.  So in your case, you can ask to create a build configuration template from each of the configs you have in project A.  You can then modify those templates to make them generic and keep the customization specific to project A in project A itself.  Then, base projects B and C's build configurations on the templates and simply customize the parts you need to in both those projects.

Here's more information: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Configuration+Template

Build configuration templates is how we have set up our build system to build multiple branches of the same source code.  When something must change, the changes are made to the templates which means they are automatically inherited by all projects that leverage said templates.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I use template extensively in my other projects. I am using version 8.1.3 of TC. The solution which you suggested will involve it cloning SPI project atleast 2 times. Any config added to SPI will have to be added again to B and C.Is there a way to have the SPI project shared among project A, B and C without cloning it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any other feature in TeamCity that allows the sharing of configurations between projects but I'm only a fellow user, not an expert.  I hope someone else chimes in with more information so I can learn something as well.